# preventDefault is not stopping default mouse handlng

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, event-handling

I have this simple angular example where I want to capture a mouse right click for a custom action. The default context menu must not show up. I read the questions here at SO. Unfortunately I cannot stop it from opening the browser built in context menu. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. (see plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/YieQh23xNUFmPrjZscGB)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Plunk</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="myController">
    <p ng-mousedown="mouseClicked($event)">Click me!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.mouseClicked = function(event) {
    if (event.button===2) {
      $log.debug('right mouse click detected')
      // don't do anything else
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to disable the context menu, you need to listen to the `contextmenu` event in order to stop it.

To achieve this in angular, maybe you need to add a custom directive:

```
app.directive('noContextMenu', [function() {
  return function(scope, ele, attr){
    ele.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}]);
```

```
<p no-context-menu >Click me!</p>
```